# Can't run requirejs on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, requirejs

I need some advice. I trying to use nodejs + requirejs on heroku.
My project structure is pretty common:

```
\
|-\app
|-\build
|-\config
|-\node-modules
|-\public
|
|-server.js
|-etc...
```

The build folder is a result of "gulp build". Locally everything is fine, but when I trying to run my app on heroku, I see that content of requirejs just duplicates my template of index page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>myapp</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="main" class="container"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
    <div id="modal"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" data-main="js/main" src="/js/vendors/require.js">
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <title>myapp</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="header"></div>
            <div id="main" class="container"></div>
            <div id="footer"></div>
            <div id="modal"></div>
            <script src="/js/vendors/require.js" data-main="js/main" type="text/javascript"></script>
        </body>
        </html>
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

js/main contents some config for requirejs and stats app.

```
require.config({
  basePath: '/js/',

  paths: {
    jquery: 'vendors/jquery',
    bootstrap: 'vendors/bootstrap',
    underscore: 'vendors/lodash.underscore',
    backbone: 'vendors/backbone',
    marionette: 'vendors/backbone.marionette',
    'backbone.associations': 'vendors/backbone-associations',
    'backbone.stickit': 'vendors/backbone.stickit',
    'localstorage': 'vendors/backbone.localStorage',
    hbs: 'vendors/hbs',
    handlebars: 'vendors/handlebars',
    marrionette_hbs: 'lib/marionette.handlebars',
    'bootstrap-multiselect': 'vendors/bootstrap-multiselect',
    'jquery.cookie': 'vendors/jquery.cookie'
  },

  shim: {
    underscore: {
      exports: '_'
    },

    backbone: {
      exports: 'Backbone',
      deps: ['jquery', 'underscore']
    },

    marionette: {
      exports: 'Marionette',
      deps: ['backbone']
    },

    marrionette_hbs: {
      exports: 'marrionette_hbs',
      deps: ['marionette', 'handlebars']
    },

    bootstrap: {
      exports: 'bootstrap',
      deps: ['jquery']
    },

    'bootstrap-multiselect': ['bootstrap'],

    'backbone.associations': ['backbone'],

    'backbone.stickit': ['backbone']

  },

  deps: ['jquery', 'bootstrap', 'marrionette_hbs', 'hbs']

});

require(['app'], function (App, hbs) {
  'use strict';

  App.start();

});
```

Please help to find what's wrong!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in "gulp install". After it has been added to "postinstall" option of my package.json, everything works fine.